# Fishing coaxial through two floors and foam insulated holes in fire block

Tags: coaxial-cable

I've got a bundle of coaxial cables running from the cable connection on the ground floor to the attic above the first floor - a distance of roughly 20 feet. Initially, I planned on using one of the lines to fish through a few strands of paracord and be done with it. However, I've now realized that spray foam was applied at each pass the bundle makes through a fire break (this should have been obvious to me). I'm wondering what my options are for getting new cable up along the path the original bundle takes. Additionally, there's no guarantee that it's a straight path.

Are there any clever options that don't require breaking down drywall?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a fire break between floors? Or you need to pass horizontally through walls as well? I'd think the foam was just for insulation purposes to prevent air infiltration. If you can access the foam just dig a hole through it. Had to do that when replacing a plumbing line once where they had encased the thing in foam to prevent drafts.

Comment: [Electric wire fishing](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/electric-wire-fishing)

Answer (score 1):

Your options are to engineer a new path or to open up the drywall around the places where the spray foam was used. This shouldn't be a major problem as drywall is easily patched and refinished.

Even with finding a new path you may very well have to open up access holes to allow for drilling through fire blocks or the top/bottom plates at floor transitions.